# Invalid Date Error when the max-Date is cleared

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have two input fields which are datepickers "startDate" and "endDate". For startDate the max-date should be endDate. For endDate the min-date should be startDate. when i clear startDate and try to set new date for endDate it is giving "Invalid Date Error" because the min-Date(StartDate) value is cleared. Please help me on this

```
<div class="col l2 m4 s12 input-field">
    <input id="startDate" type="text" ng-model="startDate" date-picker="date" format="D/M/YYYY" max-date="endDate" />
    <label material-active="startDate" for="startDate">Min. Created Date</label>
    <a class="clear-button" href="#" ng-click="clearDate($event, 'startDate')" ng-show="startDate">X</a>
</div>
<div class="col l2 m4 s12 input-field">
    <input id="endDate" type="text" ng-model="endDate" date-picker="date" format="D/M/YYYY" min-date="startDate" />
    <label material-active="endDate" for="endDate">Max. Created Date</label>
    <a class="clear-button" href="#" ng-click="clearDate($event, 'endDate')" ng-show="endDate">X</a>
</div>


scope.clearDate = function (e, prop) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            scope[prop] = '';
                        }
```

Comment: You could add onChange listener for the fields and verify it with a couple lines of javascript, so that you can check for null values.

Answer (score 0):

please check with your date format value, `format="D/M/YYYY"`
try with `format="dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: I tried this Solution but still issue is there.. am using bootstrapMaterialDatePicker